# create array of indexed controls in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new in Wpf, but have some experiences with WinForms and VisualBasic.

In WinForms it is pretty easy create an array of controls :

```vb
Public txtN() As TextBox* 
Public xN As Integer  
...
For Me.xN = 0 To 11     ' twelve fields!
  ReDim Preserve txtN(xN)
  txtN(xN) = New TextBox
  With txtN(xN)
    .Name = "txtN" & xN : .Parent = Me
    .BackColor = Color.White : .ForeColor = Color.Black
    .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None : .AllowDrop = True
    .Width = 63 : .Height = 17
    .Top = 255 : .Left = 22 + (xN * (.Width + 18))
    .TabStop = False : .TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right
    .Tag = xN : .Visible = True : .BringToFront()
    .Text = ""
  End With
  AddHandler txtN(xN).KeyPress, AddressOf txtN_KeyPress
  AddHandler txtN(xN).Click, AddressOf txtN_Click
Next
txtN(0).Visible = False
```

and then use particular controls with

```vb
txtN(0).text = "..."
txtN(1).text = "..."
...
txtN(11).ForeColor = Color.Red
...
```

I am trying to do this in Wpf - but without any success.

Comment: That is not the way how you should work with WPF - it is possible, but it is a lot easier to walk on the [MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern) way

Comment: You would typically use an [ItemsControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol?view=windowsdesktop-6.0). The "array of controls" would be created via the ItemTemplate of the ItemControl. Take a look at [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: **NB:** Your WinForms code is horribly inefficient. Calling `ReDim Preserve` creates a new array of the requested size, copies across all elements from the old array, and then throws the old array away. If you know the size up front, it's better to create an array of the required size; otherwise, use a `List<T>` instead of an array.